# How to delete images from a folder using PHP Script

Tags: php

We need to delete  images created in linux file system. in a path `/home/user/img/` (All images)

We have tried using `unlink()` but it is taking lot of time to delete it.
Can someone help us how to delete images using linux commands must be passed with php script. I think `rm` command can do quickly but i am confused how to use

Our script:

```
$locationIMG_p="/home/user/img/";
$location_p="/home/user/img/";

$opend=opendir($locationIMG_p);

while(false!==($rf=readdir($opend)))
{           
    unlink($locationIMG_p.$rf);
}         

closedir($opend);
```

Comment: I can't see a command that is faster than unlink for what you want. You could potentially move the image to a temp folder and have a cronjob clear out that folder every hour or something, but I doubt that is faster =/

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try using shell command for this?

`$cmd = "rm -f {$locationIMG_p}*";
exec($cmd);`

But You must be very careful when using this ;)

//edit
You should add some validation at path and use [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.escapeshellarg.php)

//edit2

Also You can try using DirectoryIterator as follows:

```
$di = new DirectoryIterator(path);
foreach($di as $file)
{
   if( $file->isFile() )
   {
        unlink($file->getPathname());
   }
}
```

Comment: +1, Definitely fast and great solution to use it on a linux host (as Kiran)

Comment: Hi Bartosz ,Thanks, for replay

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(glob('/www/images/*.*') as $file)
    if(is_file($file))
        @unlink($file);
```

`glob()` returns a list of file matching a wildcard pattern.

`unlink()` deletes the given file name (and returns if it was successful or not).

The `@` before PHP function names forces PHP to suppress function errors.

The wildcard depends on what you want to delete. `*.*` is for all files, while `*.jpg` is for jpg files. Note that `glob` also returns directories, so If you have a directory named `images.jpg`, it will return it as well, thus causing `unlink` to fail since it deletes files only.

`is_file()` ensures you only attempt to delete files.

Also read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) for more details...